# Angular - tooltip when line breaks

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive with the following functionalty:

when the line breaks (no more place in the div) a tooltip will be created (with the full text) and the text will get cut and replaced by 3 dots.

[image: example]

everything i found so far is for multi line, the best i got is this:

css:

```
.trim-info {
    max-width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

template:

```
'<div class="trim-info" uib-tooltip="{{lineCtrl.text}}">{{lineCtrl.text}}</div>'
```

But, as you can see the width is hardcoded.
My question is how can I make it dynamcily to the parent width.

Comment: what is hardcoded? you already did used scope varibles there..

Comment: the width is hard coded, it is set to 50 px

Comment: You should not be needing to hardcode the width, the tooltip normally inherits the parent div width

Comment: if i don't set the widht, there will not be 3 dots and the all text will be visibile. the tooltip isn't the issue here

Comment: I'm happy help with the directive, but I did want to point out that this kind of tooltip can be done in pure CSS. It does not require a directive. A Google search for 'CSS tooltip' or 'pure CSS tooltip' will yield many results.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the tooltip to match the width of the text element that was truncated with ellipses?

Comment: No i am asking how to truncate the text element without giving him hardcoded width

Answer (score 6):

In css you can do

```
.parent-div {
    display: flex;
}

.text-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
    min-width: 0;
}
```

In your directive you can check

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('tooltip', function() {
    function isEllipsisActive(e) {
         return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) { 
          var addTooltip = isEllipsisActive(el);
        }
    };
}
```

And then depending on this value enable tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a realy simple way to do it with some jQuery.
The styling is up to you :)

```js
$('.tooltip-bottom').each(function() {
  var after = $(this).clone();
  after.removeClass('tooltip-bottom')
       .removeClass('small')
       .addClass('tooltip')
       .css({"position": "absolute",
             "top": ($(this).position().top + $(this).height() ) + "px",
             "left": $(this).position().left + "px"});
  
  $('.MyContainer').append(after);
});
```

```css
.small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.small:hover ~ .tooltip {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MyContainer">
  <div class="small tooltip-bottom">this is a very small div</div>
</div>
```